# How Do I Set a Discrete X Axis for my ggplot2 Line Plot Without Losing my Lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a dataframe like this:

```
corrtable <- data.frame(genes_included = c(rep(100,4),rep(1000,4),rep(5000,4),rep(10000,4)), percent_map_to_origin = runif(16), variation = rep(c("TCGA", "TCGA", "GTEx", "GTEx"),4), purity = rep(c("Included", "Excluded"),8))
```

I want to generate a lineplot in ggplot2 of the above with a horizontal line at, for example, 0.99554361.

I have previously done the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(corr_table, aes(x = genes_included, y = percent_map_to_origin, color = variation, linetype = purity)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point() +
geom_hline(yintercept=0.99554361, color="darkslategray") +
labs(x = "Number of Genes Included", y = "% of Cell Lines That Correlate Highest to Origin Tissue") +
theme(text = element_text(face = "bold"), legend.text = element_text(size = 16), legend.title = element_text(size = 18), axis.title = element_text(size = 12), axis.text = element_text(size = 13)) +
scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dashed", "solid"))
```

This does work, but I want to make my x-axis discrete, to where it only lists 100, 1000, 5000, and 10000 instead of a continuous axis. I have seen elsewhere to factor() your x-axis, which does work and does make my x-axis discrete, but I lose the lines connecting my dots when I do so. This is how I have been adding the factor:

```
corrtable <- data.frame(genes_included = factor(c(rep(100,4),rep(1000,4),rep(5000,4),rep(10000,4))), percent_map_to_origin = runif(16), variation = rep(c("TCGA", "TCGA", "GTEx", "GTEx"),4), purity = rep(c("Included", "Excluded"),8))
```

I'd appreciate any help making my x-axis discrete but maintaining my lines between points. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ggplot2 is probably telling you, you have to set the `group` aesthetic for your lines when using a discrete x scale, i.e. in your case do `group = interaction(variation, purity)` in `geom_line`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(corr_table, aes(x = genes_included, y = percent_map_to_origin, color = variation, linetype = purity)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(variation, purity))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.99554361, color = "darkslategray") +
  labs(x = "Number of Genes Included", y = "% of Cell Lines That Correlate Highest to Origin Tissue") +
  theme(text = element_text(face = "bold"), legend.text = element_text(size = 16), legend.title = element_text(size = 18), axis.title = element_text(size = 12), axis.text = element_text(size = 13)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed", "solid"))
```

[image]